# pthread support in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, pthreads

I downloaded pre-build library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect.

I extracted it to the following directory:
C:\Users\Veena\Documents\pthread\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release

I set following things:
In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories -> "C:\Users\Veena\Documents\pthread\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\include"

In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> linker -> General -> Additional library directories -> "C:\Users\Veena\Documents\pthread\pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release\Pre-built.2\lib\x86"

In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> 
pthreadVC2.lib 
pthreadVCE2.lib 
pthreadVSE2.lib

In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> linker -> All options -> Additional options -> 
-lpthread

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node*head;
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock;
int numThreads;

int i, j;
float mInsert, mDelete, mMember;
int data[1000];
int test[10000];
long numberOfTotalOperations = 10000;
long numberOfInsertOperations;
long numberOfDeleteOperations;
long numberOfMemberOperations;

void *Process(void* rank);
int Member(int val);
int Insert(int val);
int Delete(int val);
long getCurrentTime(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 5) {
        printf("<member op fraction> <insert op fraction> <delete op fraction>");
        exit(0);
    }
    mMember = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    mInsert = strtod(argv[2], NULL);
    mDelete = strtod(argv[3], NULL);
    numThreads = strtod(argv[4], NULL);

    numberOfInsertOperations = mInsert * numberOfTotalOperations;
    numberOfDeleteOperations = mDelete * numberOfTotalOperations;
    numberOfMemberOperations = mMember * numberOfTotalOperations;

    pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock, NULL);

    //data set : create with non-repeated random number
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        while (1) {
            int temp = rand() % 65536;
            int found = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (data[j] == temp) { found = 1; break; }
            }
            if (found == 0) { data[i] = temp; break; }
        }
    }
    //test set
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        while (1) {
            int temp = rand() % 65536;
            int found = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (test[j] == temp) { found = 1; break; }
            }
            if (found == 0) { test[i] = temp; break; }
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------- Insert,Delete,Member
    long thread;
    pthread_t* thread_handles;
    thread_handles = malloc(numThreads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (thread = 0; thread < numThreads; thread++)
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, Process, (void*)thread);

    for (thread = 0; thread < numThreads; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);


    //--------
    free(thread_handles);
    return 0;
}

void *Process(void* rank) {

    long my_rank = (long)rank;
    int i, offset = (numberOfTotalOperations * my_rank) / numThreads;
    int my_last_i = offset + (numberOfTotalOperations / numThreads);
    long insert_op = numberOfInsertOperations / numThreads;
    long delete_op = numberOfDeleteOperations / numThreads;
    long member_op = numberOfMemberOperations / numThreads;

    for (i = offset; i < my_last_i; i++) {
        if (i < offset + insert_op) {   //insert
            pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
            Insert(test[i]);
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        }
        else if (i < offset + insert_op + delete_op) {  //delete
            pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock);
            Delete(test[i]);
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        }
        else {
            pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
            Member(test[i]);
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&rwlock);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int Insert(int value)
{
    struct Node*curr_p = head;
    struct Node*pred_p = NULL;
    struct Node*temp_p;

    while (curr_p != NULL && curr_p->data < value)
    {
        pred_p = curr_p;
        curr_p = curr_p->next;
    }

    if (curr_p == NULL || curr_p->data > value)
    {
        temp_p = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp_p->data = value;
        temp_p->next = curr_p;

        if (pred_p == NULL) /** New first node */
        {
            head = temp_p;
        }
        else
        {
            pred_p->next = temp_p;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else /* value already in list*/
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int Member(int value)
{
    struct Node*curr_p = head;

    while (curr_p != NULL && curr_p->data < value)
    {
        curr_p = curr_p->next;
    }
    if (curr_p == NULL || curr_p->data > value)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int Delete(int value)
{
    struct Node*curr_p = head;
    struct Node*pred_p = NULL;

    while (curr_p != NULL && curr_p->data < value)
    {
        pred_p = curr_p;
        curr_p = curr_p->next;
    }
    if (curr_p != NULL && curr_p->data == value)
    {
        if (pred_p == NULL) /** deleting first node in list */
        {
            head = curr_p->next;
            free(curr_p);
        }
        else
        {
            pred_p->next = curr_p->next;
            free(curr_p);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else /* Value isn't in list */
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I got following errors which exhibits, pthreads are not included:
1.  IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "pthread_t *"
2.  IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Node *"
3. cannot convert from 'void *' to 'pthread_t *'
4. cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Node *'

What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Rather use MinGw GCC in this case than visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm just tried to compile your code and got the same error. It's because you should do explicit conversion void* pointer returned from malloc.

```
//thread_handles = malloc(numThreads * sizeof(pthread_t));
thread_handles = (pthread_t*)malloc(numThreads * sizeof(pthread_t)); // right one

//temp_p = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
temp_p = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // right one
```

Answer (score 0):

> In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> linker -> All options -> Additional options -> -lpthread

It's wrong. Why did you do this?

> In projects -> right click -> properties -> configuration properties -> linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> pthreadVC2.lib pthreadVCE2.lib pthreadVSE2.lib

You should link only one this *.lib file. Description from README file:

```
In general:
    pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}[c].dll
    pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}[c].lib

where:
    [VG] indicates the compiler
    V   - MS VC, or
    G   - GNU C

    {SE,CE,C} indicates the exception handling scheme
    SE  - Structured EH, or
    CE  - C++ EH, or
    C   - no exceptions - uses setjmp/longjmp

    c   - DLL compatibility number indicating ABI and API
          compatibility with applications built against
          a snapshot with the same compatibility number.
          See 'Version numbering' below.
```

Comment: When I writing code in C++ I use pthreadVCE2.lib, for C you should  probably use pthreadVC2.lib or  pthreadVCE2.lib.

Comment: I removed -lpthread and add pthreadVCE2.lib only. Still I'm getting the same error